# When the size of label changes, the size of the window changes as well in tkinter, python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I made a tkinter calculator where when I press in numbers, the label displays the numbers. The only issue is that when the label increases in width, it causes the window to change in width as well. Is there a way to keep increasing the length of the label to the left instead of to the right when I press in numbers? The code is shown below -

```
from tkinter import *

FONT_NAME = "Courier"
val = ""


# ---------------------Functionality------------

def seven_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "7"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def eight_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "8"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def nine_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "9"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def four_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "4"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def five_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "5"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def six_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "6"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def one_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "1"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def two_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "2"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def three_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "3"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


def zero_is_clicked():
    global val
    val += "0"
    solution_label.config(text=val)


# ---------------------UX------------------------


window = Tk()
window.config()
window.title("Calculator")
window.minsize()
window.resizable(0, 0)


solution_label = Label(text="0", height=2, font=(FONT_NAME, 30), bg="pink", anchor="e")
solution_label.grid(column=3, row=0)

AC_button = Button(text="AC", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
AC_button.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=3, pady=3)

division_button = Button(text="/", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
division_button.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=3, pady=3)

multiplication_button = Button(text="*", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
multiplication_button.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=3, pady=3)

subtraction_button = Button(text="-", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
subtraction_button.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=3, pady=3)

seven_button = Button(text="7", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=seven_is_clicked)
seven_button.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=3, pady=3)

eight_button = Button(text="8", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=eight_is_clicked)
eight_button.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=3, pady=3)

nine_button = Button(text="9", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=nine_is_clicked)
nine_button.grid(column=2, row=2, padx=3, pady=3)

plus_button = Button(text="+", width=6, height=6, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
plus_button.grid(column=3, row=2, rowspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)

four_button = Button(text="4", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=four_is_clicked)
four_button.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=3, pady=3)

five_button = Button(text="5", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=five_is_clicked)
five_button.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=3, pady=3)

six_button = Button(text="6", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=six_is_clicked)
six_button.grid(column=2, row=3, padx=3, pady=3)

one_button = Button(text="1", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=one_is_clicked)
one_button.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=3, pady=3)

two_button = Button(text="2", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=two_is_clicked)
two_button.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=3, pady=3)

three_button = Button(text="3", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=three_is_clicked)
three_button.grid(column=2, row=4, padx=3, pady=3)

equal_button = Button(text="=", width=6, height=6, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
equal_button.grid(column=3, row=4, rowspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)

delete_button = Button(text="Del", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
delete_button.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=3, pady=3)

zero_button = Button(text="0", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=zero_is_clicked)
zero_button.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=3, pady=3)

decimal_button = Button(text=".", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
decimal_button.grid(column=2, row=5, padx=3, pady=3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `window.geometry("widthxheight")` to set the width and height of the window.

Comment: first of you should use like one function for all numbers pressed, just pass the number pressed as an argument (basic python stuff) (and then for adding the command to buttons you probably will need to use `lambda:`) and in case you want to argue that you just started python: it doesn't matter if you just started python, if you did then what on earth are you doing with GUIs already when you should first learn the basics. the thing is that if there is a lot of repetitive code (like in this case) then there very likely is a way to reduce that code. also learn how to create buttons in a loop

Comment: also you should specify the master argument and what you probably want to do is to do this: `solution_label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, sticky='e')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer (explanation in comments):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label

FONT_NAME = "Courier"
# ---------------------UX------------------------

window = Tk()
window.config()
window.title("Calculator")
window.minsize()
window.resizable(0, 0)


solution_label = Label(text="0", height=2, font=(FONT_NAME, 30), bg="pink", anchor="e")
# added columnspan, changed column to 0 and set sticky to east, now this means that text will go to the right
# because of the columnspan and changed row, you can change sticky to `nsew` if you want the
# label to cover all sides
solution_label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=4, sticky='e')

# this is the loop for creating the number buttons
row = 0
column = 0
for num in range(1, 10):
    def add_num(number=num):
        if solution_label['text'] == '0':
            solution_label['text'] = ''
        solution_label['text'] += str(number)
    Button(
        window, text=num, width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=add_num
    ).grid(row=row + 2, column=column)

    column += 1
    if column > 2:
        column = 0
        row += 1
# separate creation for zero because the row is not shared with any other widgets
# that can be solved by creating a list with button names and iterating over that
# that way you can create all buttons in a loop (not all functions can be defined in loop however)
Button(
    window, text='0', width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0, command=lambda: add_num(0)
).grid(row=5, column=1)

AC_button = Button(text="AC", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
AC_button.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=3, pady=3)

division_button = Button(text="/", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
division_button.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=3, pady=3)

multiplication_button = Button(text="*", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
multiplication_button.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=3, pady=3)

subtraction_button = Button(text="-", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
subtraction_button.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=3, pady=3)

plus_button = Button(text="+", width=6, height=6, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
plus_button.grid(column=3, row=2, rowspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)

equal_button = Button(text="=", width=6, height=6, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
equal_button.grid(column=3, row=4, rowspan=2, padx=3, pady=3)

delete_button = Button(text="Del", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
delete_button.grid(column=0, row=5, padx=3, pady=3)

decimal_button = Button(text=".", width=6, height=2, padx=7, pady=7, highlightthickness=0)
decimal_button.grid(column=2, row=5, padx=3, pady=3)


# these two lines set window geometry so that it will not automatically resize to fit widgets
window.update_idletasks()
window.geometry(window.geometry())

window.mainloop()
```

The geometry part is the last 4 to 3 lines, it doesn't allow window to automatically resize

Comment: thank you @Matiiss. You definitely helped me learn a lot. I will definitely look into my basics more.